# Trying to get property 'count' of non-object in Views - Laravel 6.18.6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to web development , and trying to create a dashboard with laravel , and trying to pass my data to laravel but i am not being able to  do this, i getting above error,

```
Trying to get property 'count' of non-object
```

So, How can i retrieve count data and users data in my views, 
Here is my controller:

```
    public function dashboard()
{
    $countActiveUser = User::where('status',0)->get();
    $countLatestUser = User::latest()->get();
    $countBlockedUser = User::where('status',1)->get();
    $countTotalUser = User::all();
    $dataCount['activeUserCount'] = count($countActiveUser);
    $dataCount['blockedUserCount'] = count($countBlockedUser);
    $dataCount['latestUserCount'] = count($countLatestUser);
    $dataCount['allUserCount'] = count($countTotalUser);
    $data['users']=$countTotalUser;
    $data['count']=$dataCount;
    return view('dashboard',['data'=>$data,]);
}
```

and here is how i trying to retrive my values in dashboard.blade\

```
<span class="h2 font-weight-bold mb-0">{{$data->count->activeUserCount}}</span>
```

return data:

```
{
"data": {
    "user": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "user0",
            "email": "nabrajkhadka43@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "user1",
            "email": "email1@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": "Apr 15 2020",
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": "Apr 22 2020"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "user2",
            "email": "email2@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "user3",
            "email": "email3@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "user4",
            "email": "email4@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "user5",
            "email": "email5@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "user6",
            "email": "email6@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "user7",
            "email": "email7@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "user8",
            "email": "email8@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "user9",
            "email": "email9@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": null
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "hari Khadka",
            "email": "password@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": "2020-04-01-1324237408.jpg",
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": "Apr 01 2020"
        },
        {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "hari Khadka",
            "email": "emaiasdl1@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": "2020-04-10-1742149546.jpg",
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": "Apr 10 2020"
        },
        {
            "id": 27,
            "name": "alfredaosd",
            "email": "nabrajkhssadka43@gmail.com",
            "phone": null,
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "profile_pic_url": null,
            "lat": null,
            "lon": null,
            "bio": null,
            "created_at": "Apr 10 2020"
        }
    ],
    "count": {
        "activeUserCount": 9,
        "blockedUserCount": 4,
        "latestUserCount": 13,
        "allUserCount": 13
    }
}
```

}

i know this is a duplicate question but please some on help me.

Comment: $data is not array there so you can not display using foreach.

Comment: then this error comes: Trying to get property 'count' of non-object

Comment: use dd($data); before return view that will show $data you passing.

Comment: <@foreach($item->users as $user) change to <@foreach($item->user as $user)

Comment: I think you should define $data=[]; at first and then push data into it.

Comment: now i edited my question , @NiravBhoi can you loo k through it

Comment: $data['count']=$dataCount; change "count" anyother word it's guess and try
<span class="h2 font-weight-bold mb-0">{{$data['otherword']['activeUserCount']}}</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use code below to see in your view blade:

```
<span class="h2 font-weight-bold mb-0">{{$data['count']['activeUserCount']}}</span>
```

to get users one by one in your blade:

```
<table>
<tr>
    @foreach($data['user'] as $user)
        <td>{{ $user['id'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user['name'] }}</td>
    @endforeach
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you look through my question again ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code.

```
$countActiveUser = User::query()->where('status',0)->count();
$countLatestUser = User::query()->latest()->count();
$countBlockedUser = User::query()->where('status',1)->count();
$countTotalUser = User::all()->count();
```

It WIll return count in integer.

Comment: can you look through my question again ? :)